# Zoom on graph jumps to random point with d3js

Tags: d3.js

I am learning d3js and trying to incorporate zooming/panning features on a graph, however on the initial zoom event it jumps to a random spot and zooms in. After that, the zooming and panning work as expected. Why is the initial event moving the starting point and adjusting the scale oddly?

Code and example here: [bl.ocks.org/dbaileychess/7570631](http://bl.ocks.org/dbaileychess/7570631)

Answer (score -1):

This is because the zoom behaviour is attached to a different element than the one you're zooming. It determines the position of the mouse cursor relative to its own position and passes that information to the callback. If you're zooming a different element, the relative coordinates are no longer correct.

To fix, add the offset between the elements that the zoom behaviour is attached to and the elements you're zooming to the translation. This question has come up a number of times already, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072044/how-to-remove-jumpiness-upon-panning-with-d3-behavior-zoom/20072986).