# D3 v5 Zoom Stutter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use `d3.zoom` but there are some issues that I am facing. Below is the simple code that I am using.

```
var treeGroup = d3.select('.treeGroup');  //parent g element
treeGroup.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', function() {
    console.log(d3.event.transform);
    treeGroup.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
}));
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nohe76yd/9/

Below are the issues that I am facing. (Please refer above JS Fiddle for code)

- I can not zoom or pan on tree unless I do it on nodes, text labels or links hence I can not zoom on parent `g` object.
- There is a stutter when I try to pan by clicking and dragging on nodes, text labels or links
- When I zoom out an try to pan than tree disappears means there is too much translate.

If you have any idea why `d3.zoom` is behaving like this, please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072986/6060606 and adapted to this question:

```
var rootSVG = d3.select('.rootSVG');
var treeGroup = d3.select('.treeGroup');
rootSVG.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', function() {
    treeGroup.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
}));
```

This fixes the jitter and makes the entire SVG "draggable". The excellent explanation as to why this works can be found in the linked SO answer.